# QtCreator 4.1.0 dosn't show webengineview(QT 5.7) for MainWindow form editor

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtwebengine

I'm porting my app from QT 5.5 to QT 5.7. So I need to change WebKit to QWebeEngine, but I can't find QWebEngineView from Widget browser in Visual editor. How I get the QWebEngineView to Widget list.

I have added `QT += webenginewidgets` to PRO file but it dosen't show the widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need the `QWebEngineView` in the Widget palette for any specific reason? You can use any of the web engine widgets directly from code (although it is of course not as simple as a drag-and-drop). As a simple example:

```
#include <QWebEngineView>
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
QMainWindow(parent),
ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QString url = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
    QWebEngineView view = new QWebEngineView(this);
    view->load(url);
    // Sets the webview to be the main window's central widget.
    setCentralWidget(view);
}
```

Not sure if this helps you in any way. If you are really interested in having the widget in the designer, you can maybe try adding it as a custom module. Have a look at the following links:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/designer-using-custom-widgets.html
- http://www.ics.com/blog/integrating-custom-widget-qt-designer