# Qt WebEngineView not available in creator but available in designer

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer, qwebengineview

I am a bit puzzled here. In Qt Designer QWebEngineView is available but not in Qt Creator. 
The version of Qt is 5.10.1. in Windows 10.

I want to create a Dialog box that loads a webpage inside. But I can't do it in Creator. And if I make it in Designer then in Creator the QWebEngineView do not show up.
I didn't find anything in the Doc :/

Is there a workaround this?  Thank you for your help.

[Qt Creator and Qt Designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWd3S.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QtCreator 4.1.0 dosn't show webengineview(QT 5.7) for MainWindow form editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40673412/qtcreator-4-1-0-dosnt-show-webengineviewqt-5-7-for-mainwindow-form-editor)

Answer (score 2):

`QWebEngineView` is not available in Qt Creator as a drag and drop widget, but you can promote `QWebEngineView` to another widget through the Qt Creator. Just drop a QWidget for example in your Qt Creator and right-click and select Promote.

You also allocate `QWebEngineView` in the parent of any widget.

1. Drag and drop a QWidget in your Qt Creator

Allocate QWebEngineView as parent of QWidget.

```
QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView(ui->widget);
view->load(QUrl("http://qt-project.org/"));
view->show();
```